# Узнать какие транзакции выполняются для текущей схемы

Tags: sql, oracle

Пример: есть `test_schema` и выполнен запрос `update` для таблицы `test_data`, который выполняется в течение получаса.

Можно ли зная имя схемы написать запрос, который будет проверять выполняются ли сейчас `INSERT` или `UPDATE` транзакции (на вышеуказанном примере)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать поискать по тексту выполняемого sql:

```
select distinct 
       t.sql_id,          
       s.SQL_TEXT 
from   v$session t 
inner  join v$sql s 
on     t.sql_id = s.sql_id 
where  t.status = 'ACTIVE' 
and    (   upper(s.SQL_TEXT) like '%INSERT%TEST_DATA%'
        or upper(s.SQL_TEXT) like '%UPDATE%TEST_DATA%')
```

Схема не указана, так как в тексте запроса схема может отсутствовать. Потенциально, если в нескольких схемах одинаковая структура, то надо что-то еще прикрутить, чтобы понимать в какую схему ушел запрос.

Comment: Пожалуй я некорректно описал кейс. Нам известно только имя схемы. Имя же таблицы в запросе использовать нельзя. Update или Insert может выполняться и для другой таблицы схемы. Суть в том, чтобы показывать какие DML транзакции сейчас выполняются на схеме.

Comment: Как идея. Приджойнить к запросу еще `all_tables` и искать для таблицы из схемы. Например регулярками. Или явно перечислить все таблицы в блоке с `or`.  Если вдруг схема всегда указана в запросе, то можно так же по ней искать. Других идеи, как зацепиться к схеме у меня нет.

Comment: посмотрел повнимательнее Ваш запрос что выше. Там написано on     t.sql_id = t.sql_id. Может Вы имели ввиду on     t.sql_id = s.sql_id ?

Comment: @Дмитрий действительно. ` t.sql_id = s.sql_id`